# uninitialized reference member 'Widget::handler'

Tags: c++, qt

This error;

```
C:\Users\Seb\Desktop\SDIcw2\widget.cpp:6: error: uninitialized reference member 'Widget::handler' [-fpermissive]
 Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
 ^
```

has occurs after I added an event handler for my combination box. Does anyone know why? The widget ran fine before so im not sure as to why!

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

#include <QString>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::getList(SDI::shipHandler& shipHandler)
{
    handler = shipHandler;
}

void Widget::populateCombo()
{
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Select Vessel...");
    for(std::vector<SDI::navalVessels*>::const_iterator i = handler.ships.begin(); i != handler.ships.end(); ++i)
    {
        SDI::navalVessels* ship = *i;
        QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(ship->name);
        ui->comboBox->addItem(qstr);
    }
}



void Widget::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    for(std::vector<SDI::navalVessels*>::const_iterator i = handler.ships.begin(); i != handler.ships.end(); ++i)
    {
        SDI::navalVessels* ship = *i;
        QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(ship->name);
        QString str = ui->comboBox->currentText();
        if (str == qstr)
        {
            //do something here
        }
    }

}
```

trying to change the values of boxes depending on whats selected in the combo box.

Comment: What is `Widget::handler`? Please show your source code for widget.cpp/h

Comment: But what is the `handler`? How it is declared?

Comment: handler is a reference to a class created in main.cpp, that is passed through by a getter function. SDI::shipHandler sh("ships.txt"); Widget w; w.getList(sh); - then assign sh to handler in order to use it elsewhere in widget.cpp

Comment: The problem is that you declare `handler` as a reference in your class, so that it should be initialized. You can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285040/reference-as-class-member-initialization

Comment: I've declared it like so; SDI::shipHandler& sh; - in my class, so what am i doing wrong with the assignment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51736/discussion-between-horhay-and-vahancho)

Comment: You can't reassign a reference. Maybe you want to use a pointer instead?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown widget.h, but presumably you have a private section that looks something like:

```
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    ShipHandler *handler;
```

Your compiler is reminding you that uninitialized pointers can be dangerous, so you need to make sure you change your constructor to initialize them:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent),
      ui(new Ui::Widget),
      handler(0)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```