# Arduino passing in one object as a parameter in the constructor of another class

Tags: c++, object, arduino

I am very new to this so forgive me if I call something the wrong name. What I am trying to do is pass an instance of a class into the constructor of another class. I know these are normally done in .h and .cpp files but for the code I was running it didn't seem to care, I could be wrong however. I have taken out most of the code except the class defs and constructors.

I want to have some existing instance of Thermistor like coldtherm in my code and pass into the constructor of Tempcontroller so I can call coldtherm like what I show in the printfromthermistor function.

```
//Thermistor Class
    class Thermistor
{

  int Thermpin;

public:
  Thermistor(int pin)
  {
  Thermpin = pin;
  }


double TEMPOutput()
  {
  return Thermpin;
  }  
void Update()
  {

  }
};

Thermistor coldtherm(1);

//Tempcontrol Class
class TempController
{

public:

TempController(Thermistor&) //Right here I want to pass in coldtherm to the Tempcontroller and be able to call functions from that class.


void printfromthermistor()
{

  Thermistor.TEMPOutput();
}


};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285040/reference-as-class-member-initialization).

References can only be initialized, not changed.  To use it in the constructor like you have shown means that the reference member has to be *initialized* in the constructor:

```
class TempController
{
  Thermistor & member;
public:
  TempController( Thermistor & t ) { member = t; }; // assignment not allowed
  TempController( Thermistor & t ) : member(t) { }; // initialization allowed
}
```