# Copy vector by reference using template class?

Tags: c++

I have a vector and I need to copy it as a template vector class?
So if I modify one element in the original vector it needs to change in the other too.
Here is my main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include "thisheader.h"
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(6);
    
    std::vector<double> a;
    a.push_back(4.32);    
    templatevectorclass<int> vv(v);
    templatevectorclass<double> av(a);

    v[0] = 3;
    if(vv[0]==v[0]){
        std::cout << "good" ;
    }else{
        std::cout << "bad";
    }

    a[0] = 2.4;
    if(av[0]==a[0]){
        std::cout << "good" ;
    }else{
        std::cout << "bad";
    }
}
```

Here is the class that needs to copy the vector by reference:

```
#include <vector>    
template<class T1>
class templatevectorclass {
    std::vector<T1> copy;
    T1* array;

public:    
    templatevectorclass(std::vector<T1> vector) {
        for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
        {
            copy.push_back(vector[i]);

        }
    }
  
    T1 const& operator[](int index) const
    {
        return copy[index];
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: I only see you don't need the loop. Just copy = vector.

Comment: Yes, I want to copy the vector to a template class using reference, so if I change the value the original vector, the template class vector reference should change as well.
Idk how to use references , could you help me?

Comment: Could you provide me a code? I don't know how to copy the vector with reference?
Thanks :D

Comment: Please define what is "copy by reference"? Copy is one thing, reference is another thing. The reference can't be a copy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference as class member initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285040/reference-as-class-member-initialization)

Comment: "So if I modify one element in the original vector it needs to change in the other too" Are you sure that you don't just need a *reference* of the original vector (whitout any copy)?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you would like to store reference inside `templatevectorclass`

```
template<class T1>
class templatevectorclass {
    std::vector<T1> &reference;

public:    
    templatevectorclass(std::vector<T1> &vector) : reference(vector) {
    }
  
    T1 const& operator[](int index) const
    {
        return reference[index];
    }
};
```

Comment: So, the question would sound "Store a reference to a vector".